# Best Way to Concatenate Conditionally on Multiple Cell Contents

Tags: excel, concatenation

I have an excel table with the following headers

```
Name      Occupation     Income     Martial Status   Spouse Income 
Amy       Astronaut      H          M                     NA
Ben       Baker          M          S                     NA
Carl      NA             NA         M                     H
Dan       NA             NA         S                     NA
Eric      NA             NA         NA                    NA
```

I wish to concatenate these into a single cell only if the cell is not "NA", ie I want to create a column that says the following:

```
Amy_Astronaut_H_M
Ben_Baker_M_S
Carl_M_H
Dan_S
Eric
```

Currently what I have in mind is a series of ifs like so:

```
=Name&"_"&if(istext(search("NA',Occupation,"")),"",Occupation&"_")
         &if(istext(search("NA',Income,"")),"",Income&"_")
         &if(istext(search("NA',Marital Status,"")),"",Marital Status&"_")
         &if(istext(search("NA',Spouse Income,"")),"",Spouse Income&"_")
```

Without changing the contents of the existing table, I am wondering if there is a slightly more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for your example. If you have later versions of Excel you can use TEXTJOIN rather than CONCATENATE.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1&"_"&B1&"_"&C1&"_"&D1&"_"&E1,"_NA","")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @SJR, this works perfectly and was exactly what I was hoping for! Thanks for taking the time! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following information:

```
   A    B    C   D
1  
2       A   NA   B
```

In cells B3 to D3, I've put the following formula:

```
=IF(B2="NA";"";B2) // Change to C and D accordingly
```

In cell B4, I've put following formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN("_";TRUE;B3:D3)
```

The value is `A_B`.